# Catch errors in views without execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I try to pull a list of views with their errors, without executing them.

Here is an example in the code below:

```
create view vw_first as
select id, first_name, last_name
from dim_employees

create view vw_second as
select id, first_name
from dim_employees

create view vw_third as 
select b.id, a.first_name, last_name -- no prefix of table alias
from vw_first a
     join vw_second b on a.id = b.id

--- Here the issue begin

alter view vw_second as 
select id, first_name, last_name
from dim_employees


--- Now, when I run the vw_third view I will get Ambiguous column error.

select *
from vw_third
```

For this situation, I need a monitor or a way to get a list of those views that will cause errors.

I familiar with `sp_viewrefresh` procedure, but it runs and locks the views and the tables within them.

I need a way to find them without executing them.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Do you have an XY problem?

Comment: *"Here the issue begin"* And what is that issue..?

Comment: I advice against creating a view that selects from another view, the performance will suffer greatly

Comment: You can always try a query on `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

Comment: Why not fix the views pro-actively so they aren't vulnerable to this issue in the first place? (rather than trying to detect the issue after the fact). Also do you not have any non production environment that you can run these checks on so even if locking does occur it is not an issue?

Comment: @Larnu - Last_name column has no table alias (ex a.last_name, its just last_name). So later on when I add last_name field to vw_second, vw_second has ambigous error. Got it?

Comment: @MartinSmith - We have about 300 views with bad practices and we need to handle it quick

Comment: Learn from the problem by qualifying *all* your columns, @Eliran . I joined a company about a decade about and very quickly found out that they hadn't qualified any of their columns when the business application had a new column added to a "core" table; many of the views fell over with ambiguous column errors. I, and another developer at the time, spent the entire week reviewing every view and qualifying the columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a mechanism that prevent you from altering view which is used in another object. Fortunately SQL Server implemented this feature with adding `WITH SCHEMABINDING` in definition of view.

For example when you create or alter third view like this:

```
create view vw_third
WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
select b.id, a.first_name, last_name -- no prefix of table alias
from vw_first a
     join vw_second b on a.id = b.id
```

SQL Server prevent you from altering first and second view. So you will inform that the view you are altering is used in third view.

Comment: Schema-bound views cannot use columsn without table references anyway, so `last_name -- no prefix of table alias` is just wrong. This does solve the problem, but for a different reason